# Transfer project from one application to another

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, software

As a beginner, I would like to know how important it is which software I decide to start out with. (Currently eyeing Adobe Premiere Elements and Sony Movie Studio 13).

I realize that whichever one I'll use, if I decide to switch application, I'll need to learn the other's interface and terminology. However, I was wondering about something else - Can I transfer a project from one to the other. Say I want to make a change to a video I created in one application, and obviously I don't want to input the created video (both because I lose resolution, and because I want each sound track separate etc.) - is it possible to transfer the video to other video editors, or will this project be "stuck" to this editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to transfer projects between different video editing programs, but they are **very** limited. Take a look at [my answer here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/how-can-i-save-the-project-for-premiere-cs-5-5/14887#14887); this question is about transfering projects between different versions of Premiere Pro, but the answer is basically the same. You can export a project as an [Edit Decision List (EDL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_decision_list), however this will only contain the arrangement of the clips in the timeline (namely your *edit decisions*, hence the name), any effects, e.g. color-grading, will be lost. Another format that does basically the same is [AAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Authoring_Format). I'm not sure about the differences between both formats, but either way, most of your post-production efforts will be lost when transfering the project to a different program.

Also, this applies to prosumer-/production-level software. I'm not sure whether "low-end" software supports importing and exporting EDL-files. If I remember correctly, it's not possible with Premiere Elements; don't know about the Sony programs (you should be able to find that out over the developer's websites and/or Google).